# Imported functions aren't working even with __init__

Tags: python, init

I've been learning programming for about a month now and I've really tried to find the answer on my own, so I'm really sorry if this turns out to be something obvious.

I'm working on a game of hangman as a starter project and have run into a hitch.
I'd like to import a file from a different directory that will handle all of the shapes turtle is going to draw, the functions in the `polygon.py` file work as long as they aren't imported. A bit of my code is below, I'm not really worried about the code itself at the moment (as it's a work in progress) so much as when the program hits `square(t, 100)` I get an error `NameError: name 'square' is not defined`. I have an `__init__.py` in `Test_Programs` that's blank and one in `Shapes` that has `from polygon import *`. I've tried varying between one or the other and nothing seems to work. Sorry for the long explanation, just trying to avoid saying 'Tried that!' Much Thanks!

```
import random, turtle, math, os, sys

sys.path.insert(0, 'C:\School\Intro to Prog. 6.00\Test_Programs\Shapes')

import polygon

t = turtle.Turtle()
t.speed(6)

alphabet = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l',
            'm','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']

def DrawNoose():##Draws up the game   
    t.pu()          
    t.setx(-50)
    t.pd()
    square(t, 100)   
    t.sety(100)
    t.fd(50)
    t.sety(200)
    t.fd(100)
    t.sety(150)

DrawNoose()
```

(I've also cut my code down to just what's causing the error in case anything isn't making sense)

Comment: Perhaps you meant `from polygon import square`, or `polygon.square(t, 100)`?

Comment: Please do feel free to add any help regarding the sloppiness of my code!

Comment: that does work actually! so thank you! the problem is I've got a couple shape functions I'd like to be able to call from polygon

Comment: @StillLearnin `from polygon import square, circle, oval, rectangle` will work, or just write their qualified names (`polygon.square`, `polygon.circle`, etc)

Comment: oh awesome! I didn't realize could throw the functions together like that thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're simply missing a `t.` in front of the square function, so it should say `t.square(t, 100)` rather than just `square(t, 100)`.

Comment: wow, just didn't look hard enough! thank you that was exactly it